# Interesting relationship between the 2D Harmonic Oscillator and Pauli Spin matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, harmonic-oscillator, lie-algebra

I have an isotropic 2D Harmonic Oscillator in cartesian coordinates
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p_x^2}{2m} + \frac{p_y^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} m\omega^2 (x^2 + y^2)
\end{equation}
In terms of the usual creation and annihilation operators for the $x$ and $y$ modes, $n_x$ and $n_y$ this can be written as
\begin{equation}
H = \hbar\omega(n_x^\dagger n_x + n_y^\dagger n_y + 1)
\end{equation}
Now we can 'construct', three operators that commute with the Hamiltonian, apart from the (trivial) number operators $N_x$ and $N_y$:
\begin{align}
V_x &= a_x^\dagger a_y + a_y^\dagger a_x\\
V_y &= i(a_y^\dagger a_x - a_x^\dagger a_y)\\
V_z &= a_x^\dagger a_x - a_y^\dagger a_y
\end{align}
Now these operators can been proved to satisfy the commutation relations of angular momentum. In fact,

\begin{equation}
V_i = a^\dagger \sigma_i a
\end{equation}
Where $a = \begin{pmatrix} a_x & a_y \end{pmatrix}$ and $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices. This is really surprising to me as I don't see why and how this must be true. Can someone shed some light on this? I think for $2s+1$ dimensions, we can 'construct' such operators using the matrix representations of spin $s$. However, I haven't seen a proof of this.

Comment: [Jordan, 1935](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map). Covered in any good group theory course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known the operators
$$
\hat C_{ij}=a_i^\dagger a_j\, ,i, j=1,\ldots, n
$$
span the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.  If you choose $\hat C_{ij}, i\ne j$ and use $h_i= \hat C_{ii}-\hat C_{i+1,i+1}$, you get instead the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.  Yours is just the special case with $n=2$.

The $n=3$ case is discussed in details in

> Fradkin DM. Three-dimensional isotropic harmonic oscillator and
> SU$_3$. American Journal of Physics. 1965 Mar;33(3):207-11,

and indeed the connection with harmonic oscillator for general $n$ goes back to

> Jauch JM, Hill EL. On the problem of degeneracy in quantum mechanics. Physical Review. 1940 Apr 1;57(7):641.

Note that general representations (not of the fully symmetric type) of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$  having Young diagrams with $m<n$ rows usually start with $U(m\times n)\supset U(m)\otimes U(n)$ so the bosons $a^\dagger_{\alpha i}$, $\alpha=1,\ldots m$, $i=1,\ldots,n$,
etc and the operators
$$
\hat C_{ij}=\sum_\alpha a^\dagger_{\alpha i}a_{\alpha j}\, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian in question has cylindrical symmetry, and can be transformed to cylindrical coordinates (i.e. $x,y\longrightarrow r, \phi$). The wave function then decomposes into radial and angular part, and the eigenstates obtained called *Fock-Darwin states*. Interestingly, the solution is simple also works with magnetic field, which affects only the angular momentum. You can google to find more information, e.g., [here](https://nbi.ku.dk/english/theses/bachelor-theses/mariek-van-beest/BachelorThesisMariekeVanBeest.pdf).

Perhaps another way to see it is in terms of Schwinger bosons ([google again](http://image.sciencenet.cn/olddata/kexue.com.cn/upload/blog/file/2010/1/2010114153918742912.pdf)), which is a representation of angular momentum in terms of two bosons, i.e., two oscillators.