# Basis representation for isotropic 2D quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics

The basis functions of the 2D isotropic quantum harmonic oscillator are of the form

$$ \psi_{n,\ell} (r,\varphi) = A_{n\ell}(r)e^{i\ell\varphi}$$

where $A_{n\ell}(r) = \frac{\sqrt{2 \times p!}}{\sqrt{(p+\vert\ell\vert)!}} e^{-r^2/2} r^{\vert \ell \vert} L_p^{\vert \ell \vert}(r^2)$ where $p=\frac{n-\vert \ell \vert}{2}.$

They are e.g. derived in (2.10), (2.11) here [in this reference.](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.89.063813)

I am now curious if one can derive the matrix elements

$$\langle \psi_{n,\ell}\vert T \vert \psi_{m,\ell'} \rangle$$

for the two operators $T = r^2$ and $T = e^{-i\varphi} (-i\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{3}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial {\varphi}}).$
I somehow feel that these two things should be well-known but I could not find this online. Is this somehow easy? The involved integrals seems very delicate.

I would be very interested in getting the ladder operator representation mentioned in the comments to work, but I do not quite know how to set it up in this case for my operators.

Comment: You might want to google *Fock-Darwin states*. [See also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/739045/247642)

Comment: What did you not like about my answer?

Comment: I’ve deleted my lengthy, detailed answer since you didn’t accept it and didn’t award your bounty to either me or Christophe. I will assume that my answer was too flawed to remain. Your 100 points went “poof”, not to me.

Answer (score 1):

The average $\langle r^2\rangle$ can be computed using [Hellmann-Feynman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem). Since the eigen-energies are $E_{p,l}=\hbar\omega(2p+|l|+1)$ with $p=(n-|l|)/2$, then
$${\partial E_{p,l}\over\partial\omega}
   =\langle {\partial H\over\partial\omega}\rangle$$
gives
$$\hbar(2p+|l|+1)=m\omega\langle r^2\rangle$$
and finally
$$\langle r^2\rangle
   =\langle\psi_{p,l}| r^2|\psi_{p,l}\rangle
   ={\hbar\over m\omega}(2p+|l|+1)$$

Comment: I don’t think your $n$ is the OP’s $n$.

Comment: You are right! I think that my quantum number $n$ is the one denoted $p$ by the OP. I will update my answer (not really an answer to the question...). Thanks for having pointed out the mistake!